# 5.x twitter app issue

Tags: iphone, ios, twitter

I am trying to trigger a call to twitter app and tweet some useful info from my phone.

When i have configured twitter already on 5.x phone it works perfect and no issues come up. On the same line, if the twitter is not configured already it doesn't do anything, no response nothing.

**do you have any suggestion so that twitter app will be opened and user can still tweet.** Thanks.

please help me to fix this issue.

Comment: Have you checked `canSendTweet` on `TWTweetComposeViewController`? How are you displaying the tweet?

Comment: TWTweetComposeViewController *tweetViewController = [[TWTweetComposeViewController alloc] init]; with a check to canSendTweet

Comment: So what does `canSendTweet` tell you?

Comment: it says NO, i know thats the reason but want to find out a way to make the user to configure it

Comment: For me it shows an alert, asking the user to configure it if I present the compose view. How are you presenting the compose view?

Comment: alert ? what was the text in it ? you configured that or is it a default one ? . . i set the initial text, image and just present it inside canSentTweet {}

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12541/discussion-between-david-ronnqvist-and-thndrkiss)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

credit goes to @david Ronnqvist. it is very simple, just remove canSendTweet it has a failsafe which takes the user to settings->twitter